# Sharing JNI Object between threads in linux

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, concurrency, java-native-interface

I'm having a problem with sharing a object bound to JNI library between different threads in Linux and I'm trying to understand why is being caused and what's causing it?

Here's the scenario:

- I have a 3rd party (let's call it LIB) library written in C for both windows and Linux (I have no access to the source code but let's assume that everything is OK with that library for the sake of this discussion)
- I've created a JNI wrapper that exposes a set of methods called from Java, this methods are then calling the functions from LIB
- There's a Java object (let's call it OBJ) that loads the JNI wrapper and calls its functions

I have 2 threads T1 and T2 in Java Application, I'm instantiating OBJ in T1 calling some functions on it (which in the back call the JNI wrapper which calls the LIB). I'm passing OBJ to T2, now on Windows everything works without problem - OBJ, JNI Wrapper and LIB maintain its state, in LINUX however OBJ keeps its state but it seems as if the LIB doesn't.

To make it more clear, let's say that LIB has two functions: `setValue(a)` and `getValue(a)`, in windows if I call `setValue(1)` in T1 and then `getValue()` in T2 (through OBJ and JNI of course) i will get the value 1, in LINUX I'm getting garbage as if the state/LIB instance was lost.

Threads are synchronized, i.e. there's a mechanism in place that ensures that T2 won't make any calls  to OBJ before T1 initializes OBJ and during T1 calls to OBJ, e.g.:

```
OBJ driver = new OBJ();

Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(driver) {
            driver.setValue(99);
        }
    }
});

Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(driver) {
            System.out.println("Value : " + driver.getValue());
        }
    }
});

t1.start();
t1.join();

t2.start();
t2.join();
```

It is possible that there's a bug in the LINUX version of LIB, but assuming there's not, is there something i'm missing here regarding JNI, Java, Processes/Threads way of working in Linux and Windows that would explain this behavior?

Comment: Is there a mechanism that ensures T1 won't make calls to OBJ during T2's calls to OBJ? IOW Are you using Java synchronization correctly?

Comment: Yes, I just edited my post to add that line. Threads are synchronized.

Comment: You haven't actually answed my question. You need to post some code.

Comment: Added  the code. I substituted the object class name and method names as it's proprietary software. The given code works on windows, Value is 99, but it doesn't work on linux (OpenSuse). Any ideas?

Comment: Without knowing anything about the implementation of the library, it's impossible to know if there's some library state that is thread specific under Linux.

Comment: I know. But I'm trying to first eliminate errors on my end.

Comment: Put debug code in your wrapper to see if your values are messed up before returning to Java. That would indicate an error in LIB